# Need exact 10 parent rows with inner row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[image]how to show 10  parent rows with inner row in first page.

Below is my code.

```js
$(".table thead").css({
  "background": "#616264"
});
$("#innertable thead").css({
  "background": "#616264 "
});
$('th').css({
  "color": "#ffffff"
});
$(".pagination").css({
  "margin-left": "200px"
});
$("td").css({
  "display": "flex",
  "justify-content": "space-between",
  "margin-bottom": "25px"
})
$("table").css({
  "border": "0",
  "border-collapse": "separate",
  "border-spacing": "0 10px",
  "margin-top": "0px",
  "margin-bottom": "0px"
});
$("td[colspan=8]").css({
  "padding": "0"
});
$(".container").css({
  "background": "#f2f2f2"
});
$("td[colspan=8]").css({
  "padding": "0",
  "border-top-width": "0"
});
$(".accordion").css("border-width", "0");
$(".pg-margin-auto").css({
  "margin": "0 auto"
});
$(".tab2").css({
  "margin-top": "0",
  "margin-bottom": "0"
});
$(".tab2 td").css({
  "border-left": "0"
});
$("#dataTable td").css({
  "border-left": "0"
});
$(".spanId").css({
  "color": "#ffd700"
});
$(".table .td").css({
  "vertical-align": "middle"
})

var mydata = [{
    "item": "V400091-Amber Bottle Clear",
    "vendor": "Alpha Packaging",
    "vendor_location": "St. Louis, Mo",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.09",
    "max_cost": "$0.14",
    "total_quantity_sold": "80,000,000",
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Silgan",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "Business Unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
    ],

  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Berlin",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "Business Unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Silgan",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "Business Unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Silgan",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "Business Unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Silgan",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "Business Unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",

  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",

  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "Bottle",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Silgan",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "business_unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "business_unit": "23-Lock Port",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]

      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Berry Plastic",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "February 20, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
    "inner_data": [{
        "vendor_name": "Berlin",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "November 2, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06",
        "product_info": [{
            "business_unit": "04-Kansas City",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          },
          {
            "Business Unit": "02-Dailas",
            "berlin_item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
            "last_purchase": "1000 pallets@$0.09",
            "total_unit_purchased": "June 21,2017",
            "average_unit_cost": "$0.14"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "vendor_name": "Alpha Packaging",
        "location": "Aurora, IL",
        "last_purchase_date": "January 12, 2018",
        "total_unit_purchased": "$0.06"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "item": "V400091-Liquor BTL 500ML",
    "vendor": "Berry Plastic",
    "vendor_location": "Aurora, IL",
    "BU": 23,
    "min_cost": "$0.06",
    "avg_cost": "$0.06",
    "max_cost": "$0.06",
    "total_quantity_sold": "70,000,000",
  },
  {
    "item": "Glass",
    "vendor": "Pune",
    "vendor_location": "NYC",
    "BU": 13692,
    "min_cost": 4000,
    "avg_cost": 6000,
    "max_cost": 8000,
    "total_quantity_sold": 500,
  },
]


$(function() {

  var totRows = mydata.length;
  console.log(totRows);
  var table_body = '<tbody>';
  for (i = 0; i < totRows; i++) {


    // This is main table

    table_body += `<tr id="td1" >
                        <td>
                        <a>
                            <span class="spanId"class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordionExample" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#innertable">&#8314;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">${mydata[i]["item"]}</a>
                            </td>
                        <td><a href="#">${mydata[i]["vendor"]}</a></td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["vendor_location"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["BU"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["min_cost"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["avg_cost"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["max_cost"]}</td>
                        <td>${mydata[i]["total_quantity_sold"]}</td>
                      </tr>`
    //This is Table inside table

    if (mydata[i].inner_data) {
      var len = mydata[i].inner_data.length;

      table_body += `<tr id="innerrow"class="collapse show">
    <td colspan="8"><table class="table table-hover" id="innertable">
    <thead><tr>
    <th scope="col">Vendor Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Location</th>
    <th scope="col">Last Purchase Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Total Unit Purchased</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>`
      for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        table_body += `<tr>
        <td>
        <a><span class="spanId"class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordionExample" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#producttable">&#8314;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a><a href="#">${mydata[i].inner_data[j].vendor_name}</a>
        </td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].location}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].last_purchase_date}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].total_unit_purchased}</td>
      </tr>`;




        // This is Table inside inner table


        if (mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info) {
          var len1 = mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info.length;

          table_body += `<tr id="productinfo"class="collapse show" >
    <td colspan="8">
   <table class="table table-hover" id="producttable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Business Unit</th>
        <th scope="col">Berlin Item</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Purchase</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Unit Purchased</th>
        <th scope="col">Average Unit Cost</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>`
          for (var k = 0; k < len1; k++) {
            table_body += `<tr>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].business_unit}</td>
      <td><a href="#">${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].berlin_item}</a></td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].last_purchase}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].total_unit_purchased}</td>
      <td>${mydata[i].inner_data[j].product_info[k].average_unit_cost}</td>
      </tr>`;
          }
          table_body += '</tbody></table></td></tr>';
        }
      }
      table_body += '</tbody></table></td></tr>';

    }
  }
  table_body += '</tbody>';
  $('#dataTable').append(table_body);

  $('td > a').on('click', function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();
  });

  var table = '#dataTable'
  var maxRows = 10
  var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length
  if (totalRows > maxRows) {
    $(table + ' tr:gt(40)').hide();

    var $this = $(table);

    $this.parents('tr').prevAll("tr.menu:first").css("background-color", "yellow");
    var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows)
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) {
      $('.pagination').append('<li class="page-item" data-page="' + i + '">\<a class="page-link">' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>\</li>').show();
    }
  }
  $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active')
  $('.pagination li').on('click', function() {
    var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page')
    var trIndex = 0;
    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
      trIndex++
      if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
        $(this).hide()
        $('table table tr').show();
      } else {
        $(this).show()
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
th {
  border-right: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  background: #616264 !important;
}

td {
  border-right: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#innertable,
#producttable {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#innertable td,
#producttable td {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#innertable tr,
#producttable tr {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

#innertable,
#producttable {
  border: 0;
}

#innerrow td[colspan="8"],
#productinfo td[colspan="8"] {
  padding: 0 0 0 24px !important;
  border-top-width: 0 !important;
}

.spanId {
  color: red;
  font-size: x-large;
}

#innertable thead,
#producttable thead {
  background: #616264 !important;
}

#innertable th,
#producttable th {
  color: #ffffff;
}

table #innertable,
table #producttable {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

tr#innerrow td[colspan="8"],
tr#productinfo td[colspan="8"] {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

#innertable,
#producttable {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

{{#partial "page"}}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <table id="dataTable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">item</th>
            <th scope="col">vendor</th>
            <th scope="col">Vendor Location</th>
            <th scope="col">BU</th>
            <th scope="col">Min Cost</th>
            <th scope="col">Avg Cost&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col">Max Cost&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Quantity Sold</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pg-margin-auto">
      <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Output :**

I need exact  10 parent rows(`#td1`) with inner row.

> ```
> $(table+' tr:gt(40)').hide();
>
> $(this).parents("tr").children("td").hide()
> ```

## td1  is my parent row

it tried using selector but not working

I struck here kindly help anyone to sort this.
I tried lot but no appreciable

1. accordion must collapse first
   2.one accordion click is closing and expanding all at once, that's wrong.. Each accordion should open and close corresponding table

Above code is edited.Here u can check code

Comment: This is unclear. "how to show 10 parent parent rows", parents of what? Also your expected output *hides* (as opposed to shows) things. Please elaborate, and provide a minimal example.

Comment: @Jeto kind see edited code

Comment: "exact 10 parent rows" still doesn't make sense (at least to me). What's the `tr:gt(40)` selector supposed to do? Cause it should select rows from the 41st onward.

Comment: Can you please create the output data in spread-sheet and take screen shot and explain it properly so we can give you solution on it?

Comment: @FirozTennali see pic . i want to show 10 each highlighted rows and their inner rows each page